# How to get Job ID from Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations of Recurring Integration Job using Rest API call

Tags: .net, rest, azure-functions, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I want to fetch job details from  Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations for that I need Job Id I am unbale to find out way how to get Job Id from Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations using any Rest API

[image]

Comment: Are you trying fetch details in Azure functions?

Comment: Yes I am trying to fetch deatils in Azure functions

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT I am using below enqueue Url to fetch erros   "/data/DataManagementDefinitionGroups/Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.GetExecutionErrors";

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically the following code block can retrieve the Job ID

```
POST /data/DataManagementDefinitionGroups/Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.ImportFromPackage
BODY
{
    "packageUrl":"<string>",
    "definitionGroupId":"<string>",
    "executionId":"<string>",
    "execute":<bool>,
    "overwrite":<bool>,
    "legalEntityId":"<string>"
}
```

The following link consists of the official documentation, that can help to retrieve and manage the Job ID.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-management-api

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. The linked documentation states "The ImportFromPackage API is used to initiate an import from the data package that is uploaded to the Blob storage that is associated with your implementation." and for the field `executionId`: "The ID to use for the job. This is called as Job ID in the UI. If an empty ID is assigned, a new execution ID will be created." Also note that this is the link to the data management API, not the recurring integrations API.

Answer (score 0):

Are these jobs that you have created? I think (I cannot find the reference documentation for this, strange?) that you get the message id back from Dynamics when you call the /api/connector/enqueue/ endpoint.

If you are not the party that creates the job, I do not think that you can get the id. What should the call look like that gets the id of a message that you cannot id?

You can then use the message id to get more information about the message by calling the /data/DataManagementDefinitionGroups/Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.GetMessageStatus:

```
POST /data/DataManagementDefinitionGroups/Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.GetMessageStatus
BODY
{
    "messageId":"<string>"
}
```

, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/recurring-integrations#api-for-getting-message-status